# How can i make two conditions inside a while?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to do this code but it doesn't work correctly. It works with only one of the conditions but not with the two of them together

```
var n;
 do{
        n=parseInt(readLine("n=?"))
    } while (n<0 && n>20);
```

Comment: Can you tell me which number is smaller than zero and *at the same time* bigger than 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the condition `n < 0 && n > 20` can never be true! When can an integer ever be less that `0` **and** greater than `20`?

Maybe you meant *or* which is denoted by two pipes: `||`?

i.e.

```
var n;
do {
    n = parseInt(readLine("n=?"))
} while (n < 0 || n > 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use OR instead of AND so it should look like this:

```js
var n;

do {
  n=parseInt(readLine("n=?"))
} while (n<0 || n>20);
```

Comment: While this is _probably_ true, the phrase "supposed to use OR" is a bit misleading.  Using `&&` is totally legit, but in this case, for the OP's desired logic to work, they _probably MEANT_ to use OR.